# Apache camel File i/o - Performance

Tags: java, file, file-io, apache-camel

I have a very large file, and my current estimates for the transformations I need to do to the file, put running time in at just over an hour. This is good, as it seems to be about as efficient it can be on a single thread. I am wondering though to improve performance, I feel it would be faster to process multiple smaller files in parallel. So my idea is to break the original file into N smaller segments represented as their own individual files, process those segments, then at the very end, append each file sequentially.

I already have an idea as to how I want to process each individual file in parallel, as well as how I want to reassemble the file at the end. The point I am stuck on however is how do I go about breaking the original file up into several smaller files in the context of Apache Camel?

I have googled around a bit, and I haven't really come up with anything. Currently I will be working on a solution that initally makes system calls to create the files, and then start the routes?

Comment: Did you try splitting the file(if possible) and running the indivdiual records in parrallel. I have done this with 350 000 lines csv files and got the file processed in roughly 8 minutes.

Comment: When you say 'splitting' the file, do you mean calling something like `from(file).split()....to(file)`? If so then yes and it'll do about 6 million lines every minute

Comment: You can also use streams and lambda to stream it using standard java 8 code and call this as a processor in camel. It could improve your performance. Your main issue will be logic for aggregation.